# getServerSideProps() not being called nextJS 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, axios

Was trying to get familiar with nextJS 13.
What I encountered is `getServerSideProps` function is not prerendering the page props. That's my first time trying it, so I don't know if I'm doing it wrong.

Here's the code written in `/app/login/page.js`

```
import Content from "@/components/content";
import LoginForm from "@/components/loginForm";
import Title from "@/components/title";

function Login({ message }) {
    return (
        <Content>
            <div className="ml-2 my-2">
                {message || "NextJS is ok."}
                <Title text="Login" />
            </div>
            <LoginForm />
        </Content>
    );
}

export default Login;

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    console.log("running getServerSideProps function..");
    return {
        props: { message: "NextJS is awesome!" },
    };
}
```

Key thing I'm trying to achieve here is to check the session key with axios request to the server before displaying login page. If user's logged in, user should be redirected to homepage. Here's future code if I will be able to make this function work:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
    console.log("Im running getServerSideProps funct ");
    let isLoggedIn = false;
    try {
        const response = await api.get("/users/session-check", {
            withCredentials: true,
        });
        if (response.status === 200) isLoggedIn = true;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
    if (isLoggedIn) {
        return {
            redirect: {
                destination: "/",
                permanent: false,
            },
        };
    }
    return {
        props: {},
    };
}
```

I tried to restart with `npm run dev`
Still getting the same results...

Comment: I think you're using the "old" way when it was with the pages folder.
As you are using the app folder with Next 13 you chould fetch like this : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching#async-and-await-in-server-components

Comment: Well, the reason I chose getServerSideProps to handle redirection is because it can handle SSR (server side rendering). Ofc I can make it work with "use client", and useEffect hook, but the issue is that the logged in user would see a blink of login page before being redirected. Your offered method will give me data.. I need user redirection.

Comment: If you look at the doc I linked, it is not client side. `getServerSideProps` is handled differently in Next 13 and `app` folder

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So as I mentioned in a comment you should follow this https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching#async-and-await-in-server-components as you're using Next 13 and the `app` folder.

This means you can try something like this:

```
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';
import Content from "@/components/content";
import LoginForm from "@/components/loginForm";
import Title from "@/components/title";

async function isLoggedIn() {
    try {
        const response = await api.get("/users/session-check", {
            withCredentials: true,
        });
        if (response.status === 200) return true;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
    return false;
}

export default async function Page() {
    const isLogged = await isLoggedIn();
    if (!isLogged) redirect('/');
    return (
        <Content>
            <div className="ml-2 my-2">
                {"NextJS is ok."}
                <Title text="Login" />
            </div>
            <LoginForm />
        </Content>
    );
}
```

Of course you need to add your message props.

Comment: The code you provided actually works as expected. Thank you!

Comment: How can I use cookies from the request in `isLoggedIn`?

Comment: You can use `import { cookies } from 'next/headers';` apparently, problem solved.

Comment: How can you have an `await` inside a non-`async` Page function?

Answer (score -7):

It looks like you're trying to use `getServerSideProps` to perform server-side rendering and authentication checks before the page is displayed. From your code, it seems like you're on the right track.

However, I noticed that you're not passing the props returned from `getServerSideProps` to your `Login` component. In order for the server-side props to be passed to the component, you need to modify the `Login` function to accept the `message` prop like so:

```
function Login({ message }) {
    return (
        <Content>
            <div className="ml-2 my-2">
                {message || "NextJS is ok."}
                <Title text="Login" />
            </div>
            <LoginForm />
        </Content>
    );
}
```

Additionally, since you're using `getServerSideProps`, your `npm run dev` command won't generate static HTML files for your pages. Instead, the pages will be generated on every request. So if you want to test if `getServerSideProps` is working correctly, you'll need to make a request to the page in your browser and check the console log for the output of your `console.log()` statement.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Yes, I did pass message to my component while destructuring props object. And visited /login page, it didn't call that function :/

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Just to confirm - did you pass the message prop to the Login component in your code? Also, have you tried checking the browser console log to see if there are any errors or warnings related to the getServerSideProps function?

Comment: Yes I did pass message prop to Login component. It's present in the first code snippet.
Developer tools console is empty. Assuming it's running on server side I should be able to see console.log() inside console (where I ran "npm run dev"). Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Some portions of this answer appear to have been generated from chatGPT, Please read [chatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)