# How to validate session key in NextJS 13 with SSR

Tags: reactjs, server, axios, credentials, next.js13

Yesterday I encountered a problem, that I couldn't run getServerSideProps() inside a path. For more info [getServerSideProps() not being called nextJS 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76276597/getserversideprops-not-being-called-nextjs-13) Check out this topic.

As I mentioned I want to know the best practice to validate session key still being on server side. I realized that this way I won't send cookies to express server because nextJS server side doesn't own one:

```
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';
import Content from "@/components/content";
import LoginForm from "@/components/loginForm";
import Title from "@/components/title";

async function isLoggedIn() {
    try {
        const response = await api.get("/users/session-check", {
            withCredentials: true,
        });
        if (response.status === 200) return true;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
    return false;
}

function Page() {
    const isLogged = await isLoggedIn();
    if (isLogged) redirect('/');
    return (
        <Content>
            <div className="ml-2 my-2">
                {"NextJS is ok."}
                <Title text="Login" />
            </div>
            <LoginForm />
        </Content>
    );
}

export default async Page;
```

Yesterday I tried to call a `getServerSideProps(context)` function where I would be able to parse cookies from the *context*. Unfortunately I found out that this is the old way in nextJS to run server side code.

Key functionality I'm trying to achieve is for user to be redirected to the root page `/` if he's logged in. If not, keep him on the log in screen.

Comment: Does this answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76280543/21872981

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using *cookies* from *next/headers*, final code looks like this:

```html
import api from "../api/api";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import Content from "@/components/content";
import LoginForm from "@/components/loginForm";
import Title from "@/components/title";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

async function checkCookie() {
    let isValid = false;
    await api
        .get("/users/session-check", {
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                Cookie: cookies()
                    .getAll()
                    .map(({ name, value }) => `${name}=${value}`)
                    .join("; "),
            },
        })
        .then(() => (isValid = true));
    return isValid;
}
async function Login() {
    const isLoggedIn = await checkCookie();
    if (isLoggedIn) redirect("/");
    return (
        <Content>
            <div className="ml-2 my-2">
                <Title text="Login" />
            </div>

            <LoginForm />
        </Content>
    );
}

export default Login;
```